# Let $S = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1\}$. Prove $(1-\lambda)x + \lambda y \in S$ for $x=\lambda'y$, $\lambda' < 0$.

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $S = \{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1\}$.

I've verified that $x,y \in S$ implies $(1-\lambda)x + \lambda y \in S$ when $x,y$ are linearly independent using Pythagoras and when $x = \lambda' y$ for $\lambda' \ge 0$.           $  \\ \\ \\ \\ \\  \\ \\ \\$   ($ 0\le\lambda \le 1$)

However, I've trouble with the case $\lambda' < 0$.

Considering $|(1-\lambda)x + \lambda y|^2=|(1-\lambda)\lambda'y + \lambda y|^2$, I don't get inequality saying $\le 1$.

$| x|$ denote the Euclidean distance.

Can someone help me out ?

Answer (score 0):

We have $$(1-\lambda)\lambda'y+\lambda y=(\lambda' +\lambda- \lambda\lambda')y$$
Now, we may assume without loss of generality that $|y|\geq|x|$. This gives $-1\leq \lambda'< 0$, which again gives $$-1\leq \lambda'-\lambda'\lambda\leq 0$$ If we add $\lambda$ to this, we still have $\leq 1$, and since that is the coefficient of $y$, we are done.

Comment: What if $|x| > |y|$ ?

Comment: @user111854 Then you rename them. Alternatively, you use the parametrization $(1-\lambda)y + \lambda x$ for the segment and set $y = \lambda' x$, Then you change every $y$ in my answer to an $x$, and everything works out nicely. That is what is meant by the phrase "without loss of generalization". It means that since the problem is the same no matter which of the two vectors has the label "$y$" attached to it, we might as well just assume that it's the longest one.

Comment: I've proven $|x+y| = |x| + |y|$ when $x = \lambda y$ for $\lambda \ge 0$. Can I use this for $\lambda < 0$ ?

Comment: How do you come from $-1 \le \lambda' < 0$ to $-1 \le \lambda' - \lambda' \lambda < 0$

Comment: @user111854 I do that because $\lambda' - \lambda'\lambda = \lambda'(1-\lambda)$, and since $0\geq 1-\lambda \geq 1$ the inequality follows: we take a number between $-1$ and $0$, and we multiply with a number between $0$ and $1$, then the end result is between $-1$ and $0$. As for the other question, if $\lambda < 0$, then $|x + \lambda x| = \big||x| - |\lambda x|\big|$.

Comment: Thank you, however I don't see how your last inequality can be used for what I've proved.

Comment: @user111854 Well, since $-1\leq \lambda' - \lambda'\lambda \leq 0$, and $0\leq \lambda \leq 1$, we have $-1\leq \lambda' - \lambda'\lambda +\lambda \leq 1$. This is exactly the coefficient of $y$ in $(\lambda' +\lambda- \lambda\lambda')y$. Since $y^2 \leq 1$ and $(\lambda' +\lambda- \lambda\lambda')^2\leq 1$, we are done.